# Lines and textures will not show up together

Tags: c, opengl

Here is how I draw the line and I using mouse to draw the line

```
static struct
{
  GLfloat p[MAX_POINTS][2];
  GLuint point_cnt;
} contours [ MAX_CONTOURS ] ;


GLuint point_cnt_mouse;
point_cnt_mouse = contours[contour_cnt].point_cnt;
glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glLineWidth(5.0);
int i;
int j;
for(i = 0; i <= contour_cnt; i++)
{
  GLuint point_cnt;
  point_cnt = contours[i].point_cnt;
  if (contours[i].point_cnt == 0)
  {
    glVertex2fv ( P );
    glVertex2fv ( P );
  }//if   
  else
  {
    for(j = 2; j <= point_cnt; j++)
    {
      glVertex2fv (contours[i].p[j-2]);
      glVertex2fv (contours[i].p[j-1]);               
    }//for                
  }//else
}//for
if(point_cnt_mouse > 0)
{
  glVertex2fv(contours[contour_cnt].p[point_cnt_mouse-1]);
  glVertex2fv(P);
}//if  
glEnd();
```

then I use glTexImage2D() to make GL_TEXTURE_2D then
my display is

```
void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glPushMatrix ();     
    glTranslatef(-4.0, 5.0, -6.0);
    //this is box and load texture on it
    drawPlane();
  glPopMatrix();
  glutSwapBuffers();
  glFlush();
  }

void myinit()
{
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  //load png image 
  drawLogo();
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Logo won't show up with lines, why? Can any one tell what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do the lines show up with no logo, or the logo shows up with no lines?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to disable texturing (`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) before drawing your line(s).  And re-enable (`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) before drawing your texture.

If you're using the default `GL_MODULATE` texture environment make sure to set the current color to white (`glColor3ub(255,255,255)`) before drawing with the texture.  If you draw the texture after the `glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )` in your line routine then `GL_MODULATE` will multiply all your texel RGB values by zero, giving you black everywhere.

Comment: if i use glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) then the texture will disappear

Answer (score 0):

It looks kind of suspicious to me that your `display()` function never calls `drawLogo()`.

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix ();     
    glTranslatef(-4.0, 5.0, -6.0);
    //this is box and load texture on it
    drawPlane();
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: actually I have drawPlane(), it mean Draw texture on this plane. My drawLogo() is load the png image to openGL.
    void drawPlane()
    {     
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
 glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
            
 glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
 glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            
 glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
 glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        
 glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
 glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
 printf("malegebbide鼠标的坐标， %d -0--0-> %d \n", a, b);
 glEnd();
    }